# Scope of an older version window app

Tags: windows-7, windows-8, windows-phone

I have created an app(.exe) using Win32 for window's older versions(xp,7).

But now i am having a silly doubt regarding the running environment of the app. Actually i would like to know whether i can run my app(.exe) in Windows 8 or not, which is going to be the latest version (Licensed version) of windows .

I would also like to know whether Windows 8 desktop apps will run on windows8 Phone/Tablet or not.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are several flavors of Windows in the market and coming to the market in the fall:

**Windows 7** - The 'classic' Windows; in the sense that it is a desktop OS with a Start Menu in the lower left. It runs on x86 and x64 based machines and supports Win32 based applications.

**Windows 8** - The next version of Windows. It runs on x86 and x64 based machines and supports BOTH Win32 and Windows Store applications. If your application runs on Windows 7 then it should run without changes or issues on Windows 8. Windows 8 will be available on Desktops, Laptops and Tablets.

**Windows RT** - A version of Windows 8 targeting ARM based machines. It supports ONLY Windows store application. Windows RT will be available in both Laptop and Tablet form factors.

**Windows Phone 7** - This is the current Phone platform and runs a customized version of Silverlight. It will only run applications built for Windows Phone 7.

**Windows Phone 8** - This is the next version of the Phone platform. It is based on the same kernel as Windows RT. There is however very little information regarding the development model at this time. It will however run both Windows Phone 7 and Windows Phone 8 applications.

Answer (score 1):

Your app(.exe) may be capable of running on Windows 8 in desktop mode. If it runs on Win7 then it should be fine but you'll need to test it. It won't run on WindowsRT devices (the ones which only run the "what-used-to-be-called-metro-style" apps).
Not that some tablet devices will have the ability to run desktop apps but some won't. It's not cut and dried.

Windows 8 apps of any sort will not run directly on Windows Phone (7 or 8).